# SQL using ALL AND NOT operators

Tags: sql, operator-keyword

I have a problem with operator [NOT] along with [ALL]

Given `tba`:

```
id  name
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
```

`tbb`:

```
id  name
6   a
7   b
8   c
9   d
10  e
```

and `test`:

```
id  name
4   a
5   b
7   c
```

I run the following query:

```
SELECT id, name
  FROM tbb
  WHERE (tbb.id > ALL (SELECT id FROM tba))
    AND (NOT tbb.id < ALL (SELECT id FROM test));
```

[data A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHC95.png)
[data B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0nwU.png)

The problem is in the row `| 6 | a |` Why does it return a value < than that from the row `test.id`?

Comment: Could you add a listing of what you are expecting the result to be? Perhaps with an explanation of what you are trying to achieve (for example: all records in `b` with an `id` greater than any `id` from `a` that are not members of `test`)?  Also, please add a tag for whatever flavour of sql you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully get your question.  `test.id` has three values, 4, 5, 7.  This expression:

```
tbb.id < ALL (SELECT id FROM test)
```

returns "false", because it is not true for 4 and 5.

Hence,

```
NOT tbb.id < ALL (SELECT id FROM test)
```

returns TRUE.

As a note:  I don't use the `ALL`/`SOME`/`ANY` operators (or more accurately, use them very, very, very rarely).  I think it is clearer to write:

```
tbb.id < (SELECT MIN(id) FROM test)
```